# 1940s Typeface Identification

Tags: font-identification, typefaces

I am looking for the "Swissair" font.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to **GDSE** - please take a look around at [tour] to get a sense of our community as a whole, then look at [ask] and [answer] a question, so you can learn how to frame a query well, and what to expect from replies. Please also specifically look over https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1083/what-are-the-requirements-for-font-identification-questions and refine your query once you've done so - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is a specific type of lettering with a "techno" image that was popular in the 1930s and 40s. The basic idea is being quite high-contrast but modernist in feeling, sometimes with and sometimes without serifs. This specific image is definitely not a font-people didn't use fonts for corporate logos in the 1940s, they would have an artist draw a custom one.

If you want something similar with minimal serifs, [Corvinus](https://fontsinuse.com/typefaces/7313/corvinus) is a popular font that is similar-there are several official and unofficial digitizations; [Skyline](https://store.typenetwork.com/foundry/fontbureau/fonts/skyline) is renamed. [Quirinus](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/mti/atquirinus/) is from the same period.

If you want a sans-serif, Domaine Sans by Klim is really excellent, and [his blogpost on its design](https://klim.co.nz/blog/domaine-sans-design-information/) lists a lot of similar sans-serifs from the period he looked at as influences. [Peristyle](https://www.typography.com/fonts/peristyle/overview) is new and feature-packed.

Many of the above typefaces never had italics, or they aren't available in all digitizations, but there are some. If what you specifically want is the same hyper-slant, I doubt you're going to find anything exactly similar. (Whatever you do, don't hyper-slant an existing font-it always looks awful.) [Stradivarius](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/grouptype/stradivarius/) is probably closest, it's a script based on the same kind of lettering. [Mondial](https://www.revolvertype.com/typefaces/mondial-display/) also has italics styled for display typography with extremely high contrast.

Comment: Actually, another recommendation: Tzigane by Albert Bolton. Strongly slanted, very like this design.

Answer (score 0):

It may be an old typeface edited for this logo which eventually never got digitalized. If you are looking for a close match, I would suggest you to use a tool like [WhatTheFont](https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/), which detects and tries to guess what font you input. The closest match for your image is [Tzigane Regular](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/itfmecanorma/tzigane/regular/), even though is pretty different (w is curvier in the original, and r hook is more pronounced) it could be a nice alternative to recreate the look and feel.